# Should all four PHP.ini be identical

Tags: server, apache2, php

**I am not a programmer .. just a newby**

I was not able to set the post_max_size or upload Max Values until i read posts relating to such on this forum

Thomas Ward in one of his answers indicated what the multiple PHP.ini files are used for

His descriptionsthen raised another question when i went and looked at all of them

Should all four PHP.ini be identical?

/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini.
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini

At present two are different sizes**strong text**

If the are, then my previous programmer never attend to it - then should i use the loaded PHP.ini across all others

Answer (score 1):

Four locations are for four different uses of PHP. Since they are for different uses, I would configure each one for a specific usage environment.

You did not specify how do you use PHP. I doubt you use all four versions. Since you are mentioning `post_max_size`, I guess you do not need PHP cli. I would say `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` is most probably the one you are using.

You can find out, which is the one, you are using and update only that one. To be on the safe side, you can also make all configurations identical. Other three will not be used anyway.